# Why are most (not all) github operations failing (443 connection refused) on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: git, raspberry-pi

I have a git repository that has been working fine when accessed using Odroid in my network. Now, I am porting the package to Raspberry Pi (Debian). I have been able to clone the repository to the Pi, do git adds and git commits. From the Pi, I can even mirror the entire repository back to github; the problem is that certain operations fail, i.e., doing a pull or push always results in:

fatal: unable to access 'https://github/---etc--': Failed to connect to github port 443: Connection refused

I have researched this quite a bit already, having checked the following:

- I do not have a proxy server anywhere
- I have rebooted
- I can connect to other servers from the Pi using ssh
- I can still do all operations successfully from an Odroid on the same network as the Pi

Can anyone give a suggestion on what to try next?

Comment: Can your rpi connect to https in general? (443 is https, not ssh; ssh is port 22.)

Answer (score 0):

I used the nuclear option. Some online discussions suggested an O/S issue; I reinstalled an updated O/S from distribution, rebuilt everything, and it works. Sometimes this is actually quicker than trying to determine an obscure root cause.